# How can I restore the apparmor settings for /var/lib/mysql?

Tags: mysql, apparmor

I had to stop the mysql service, blow away the `/var/lib/mysql`, then recreated it with a copy of `/var/lib/mysql` from a remote server. Such reckless action was in order to ... "import"? ... a really huge database quickly.

Now I cannot restart mysql due to apparmor, and is the first time I ever knew about it.

When trying to start the mysql service again, what I see is this:

```
developer@developer-Inspiron-5559:~$ sudo service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
developer@developer-Inspiron-5559:~$ journalctl -xe
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
ene 02 18:05:34 developer-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
ene 02 18:05:34 developer-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ene 02 18:05:35 developer-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
ene 02 18:05:35 developer-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
ene 02 18:05:35 developer-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
ene 02 18:05:35 developer-Inspiron-5559 audit[23831]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/23831/status" pid=23831 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r"
ene 02 18:05:35 developer-Inspiron-5559 audit[23831]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=23831 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_m
ene 02 18:05:35 developer-Inspiron-5559 audit[23831]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/23831/status" pid=23831 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r"
ene 02 18:05:35 developer-Inspiron-5559 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1514934335.367:51): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/23831/status" pid=23831 comm="mysqld" r
ene 02 18:05:35 developer-Inspiron-5559 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1514934335.367:52): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=23831 comm="my
ene 02 18:05:35 developer-Inspiron-5559 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1514934335.367:53): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/23831/status" pid=23831 comm="mysqld" r
ene 02 18:05:36 developer-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
ene 02 18:06:03 developer-Inspiron-5559 sudo[23927]: developer : TTY=pts/18 ; PWD=/home/developer ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service mysql start
ene 02 18:06:03 developer-Inspiron-5559 sudo[23927]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
ene 02 18:06:05 developer-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
ene 02 18:06:05 developer-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
ene 02 18:06:05 developer-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ene 02 18:06:05 developer-Inspiron-5559 sudo[23927]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
ene 02 18:06:06 developer-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
ene 02 18:06:06 developer-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
ene 02 18:06:06 developer-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
ene 02 18:06:06 developer-Inspiron-5559 audit[23982]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/23982/status" pid=23982 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r"
ene 02 18:06:06 developer-Inspiron-5559 audit[23982]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=23982 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_m
ene 02 18:06:06 developer-Inspiron-5559 audit[23982]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/23982/status" pid=23982 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r"
ene 02 18:06:06 developer-Inspiron-5559 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1514934366.079:54): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/23982/status" pid=23982 comm="mysqld" r
ene 02 18:06:06 developer-Inspiron-5559 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1514934366.079:55): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=23982 comm="my
ene 02 18:06:06 developer-Inspiron-5559 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1514934366.079:56): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/23982/status" pid=23982 comm="mysqld" r
ene 02 18:06:06 developer-Inspiron-5559 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

So, after the disaster, how can I make apparmor allow again mysql accessing that directory?

**Edit** also tried (as suggested by [oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/apparmor-and-mysql)) this one:

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

Content:

```
# Site-specific additions and overrides for usr.sbin.mysqld.
# For more details, please see /etc/apparmor.d/local/README.
/var/lib/mysql/ r,
/var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
```

And after saving...

```
$ sudo service apparmor reload  
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: That is not really a good way to do much of anything. At any rate to debug apparmor see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingApparmor . We need more information if you are having a problem, and, as you have problems with apparmor, I assume you are doing something non standard with mysql, so details on that as well as apparmor error messages.

Comment: The steps I did, is what I described. Now I am adding the dump...

Comment: I just added the dump

Comment: see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1610765 for some tips and help

Comment: None of the information you posted in your update helps in the least. Please see the link I gave you on debugging apparmor and post the apparmor denials / debugging. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingApparmor

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingApparmor#Debugging_procedure / logs, put aa into complain, etc .....